# WIndows command line to copy files

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

I am able to copy files and all its subdirectories using this command line in cmd

> xcopy /s c:\users\desktop f:\desktopFiles

However, I don't want to copy media files like mp3 or mp4. Is there a command line for that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create file with the extensions you don't want to copy, i.e.:

**excludedExtensions.txt**

```
.mp4\
.mp3\
```

Then you can use:

```
xcopy /s /exclude:excludedExtensions.txt c:\users\desktop f:\desktopFiles
```

---

You can read more about `xcopy exclude` [here](https://commandwindows.com/xcopy.htm)

Comment: Awesome! thanks! Where should I save this text file?

Comment: You're welcome! You can save it anywhere, just use the correct full path on the `xcopy`command